# Java Spring form validate double - nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

Trying to validate double

**Environment:** SpringMVC, AngularJS

**Using:** javax.validation.constraints to validate fields

**POJO:** book

```
public class Book implements Serializable{

....some fields 

enter code here
@NotNull
private double price;

// getter & setter
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Price:</label >
    <div class="col-sm-8" >
        <input type="number"
               class="form-control"
               name="price"
               ng-model="bookService.newBook.price"
               required="required"
                />
    </div >
</div >
```

Initially I have `@NotNull` but I realize because my input type is number if I don't input anything it automatically inserts 0, hence no error message.

Following some suggestions to use Regular Expression I use the following

```
 `^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$`
```

**Update POJO: book**

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\s*(?=.*[1-9])\\d*(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$")
private double price;
```

but now I am getting

```
    nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Double.] with root cause
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Double.
```

Questions:  Need to validate double, greater than zero with 2 decimal places. Is regex a better way to validate?  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you